# Reorder data table rows with duplicate column value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a data table that I use to insert records into an Oracle DB. One of the columns in the data table is "Rank" and it needs to be unique. So I am trying to reorder the rows of the data table and if there is a duplicate I need to increment it and all following rows.

```
Col1    Col2    Rank
----    ----    ----
A       B       1
C       D       2
E       F       2
G       H       3
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
Col1    Col2    Rank
----    ----    ----
A       B       1
C       D       2
E       F       3
G       H       4
```

I think the following does the ordering of data table if they are out of order but not sure how to handle duplicate ranks and incrementing:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Rank", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add("C", "D", 2);
dt.Rows.Add("G", "H", 3);
dt.Rows.Add("A", "B", 1);
dt.Rows.Add("E", "F", 2);

var dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("Rank"));
```

This will give me first table, ordered. How do I get table 2?

**Update**

I think I omitted an important part!

I initially read the records from DB into a data table. This has records ranked correctly (1, 2, 3, ...).

I then add the new record that has, say, rank 2; so now I have two records with rank 2. But I need to make sure the new record retains rank 2 and succeeding records' rank get incremented. So I cannot blindly increment ranks otherwise I might end up with new record having rank 3, and so on.

**Update 2**
Based on Tim's response: this is the line it throws invalid cast exception:

```
var dt2 = dtRules.Copy();
//dt2.DefaultView.Sort = "RANK ASC";
//dt2 = dt2.DefaultView.ToTable();
int rank = 0;

foreach (DataRow row in dt2.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(rowRank => rowRank.Field<int>("RANK")))

{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, why don't you simply assign a new value?

```
var dt2 = dt.Clone();
int rank = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt2.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Rank")))
{
    row["Rank"] = ++rank;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, this seems like a good solution. However I had omitted an important part that is in updated section of the post.

Comment: I get "specified cast is invalid" error in foreach statement.

Comment: @NoBullMan: Where exactly? Store the LINQ query before the loop and see if it's already there. `var query=dt2.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(rank => rank.Field<int>("Rank")).ToList(); foreach(...)`. However, is this your real code or have you simplified it? There is no way for an invalid cast exception in this code, because `Rank` is actually an `int`

Comment: @NoBullMan: I guess you have changed the code for your new requirements and that caused the exception.

Comment: I have it exactly as stated. For one thing it complained about rank being in Linq query as well as in the loop (when it was declared outside loop as int), only thing I changed was replace rank in query with rowRank. Also, clone just copies the structure, I replaced with copy.

Comment: @NoBullMan: I corrected the query, changed rank to r.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I had already renamed "rank" and it throws error. Please see update 2.

Comment: Tim,, I solved my problem but since the idea was from your original post, I marked it as answer.